# VMware Workstation upgrade

Tags: vmware, upgrade

I'd like to upgrade VMware Workstation 7 to the latest version to run Windows 8 (test flight). However, I'd like to use Easy Install. Should I simply run the installer over the old version or shall I remove the application first? I don't feel like reinstalling as VMware workstation creates 8 additional network interfaces on the system and I believe reinstalling them is not a good option.

Comment: Please write a more informative title.